# php find character in string but the character alone

Tags: php, string, strpos

I want to find 4 in a string. Just 4, not 44 or 14 or 4444 ...

I cannot use `strpos` because it returns 0 when 4 is found but also when 44 is found or when 444444 is found.

What function should I use?

Thanks

Comment: It returns zero because it found `4` in column `0`

Comment: @FrayneKonok I am not the one doing the guessing, you are

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) with [negative lookbehind and negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
preg_match('/((?<!4)4(?!4))/', $string, $m);
if ($m && count($m) == 2) {
  // matched "only one 4"
}
```

Comment: I think this is not just a guess, this is your answer and you understand what the OP want from this question.

Comment: @FrayneKonok, there is always a chance to not understand the OP correctly. Hi might be more specific, but I think I've understood what he meant.

Comment: I'll rephrase that. If I use the test string `$string = '444or4444or44or24';` it find `just a 4` on the final `24`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, fixed

Comment: Now it misses the leading `4` in `$string = '4or4444or44or24';` sorry to be a pain. I would try and be more help but my regex is a bit flakey at best

Comment: @RiggsFolly, but the string `'4or4444or44or24'` matches (`count($m) == 2`). I thought it is supposed to match. Whoops, the OP checked it, so I was right =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$str = 'Just 44 4 test 444';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
 // print_r($matches);


if (in_array("4", $matches[0])){
    echo "Match found";
  }
else
{
  echo "Match not found";
}
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/hrUu6)**

Comment: I cannot seem to break this one! UV

Comment: @miguelmas Check this answer it seems unbreakable